# Python return self / 'some string' syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking through a library on github and found:

```
@property
def tois(self):
    return self / 'Top of Information Store'
```

What does this return do?

Edit: Here's the [context](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/ef82d97264ba0603930719f242c8c075f82f6f8b/exchangelib/folders.py#L732).

Comment: The meaning of this return expression is context-dependent. Please show the entire class containing this code. Or at least the relevant parts of the class.

Comment: For sure there's a `__div__` method in that class?

Comment: Probably an API like [pathlib’s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators).

Comment: @Ryan not pathlib, but [exchangelib (under class `Root`)](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/master/exchangelib/folders.py) :P, and to the OP: there's a clear comment there stating what that property do...

Comment: @abccd: ah so not pathlib, but “an API like pathlib’s” ;)

Comment: @abccd. There's a comment describing what the method returns, not what the syntax does. Reading it doesn't making it evident how to use the syntax elsewhere.

Comment: @SillyFreak: you're correct. I wasn't aware you could do something like that. Thanks.

Comment: Is a Magic Method of python: __truediv__, see also https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html